# how to pull instagram photo's caption along with the photo?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, instagram

I just done to pull the instagram photo to my website and now working ahead to pull the caption of the photo. Anyone can hint me on that?

```
<div class="instafeed"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".instafeed").instagram({
        userId: 'xxx',
        accessToken: 'xxx',
        image_size: 'standard_resolution',
    });
    </script>
```

Thanks! ^.^

Comment: Hey, see this plugin: http://instafeedjs.com/. Move to templating part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is available in the `json` feed sent by instagram to the plugin your using. it's inside the location attribute.

> location":{"latitude":-23.241574214,"name":"the beatles - a hard day's
>   night","longitude":-45.886599107,"id":133717757}